# Why does Gson fromJson throw a JsonSyntaxException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY?

Tags: java, json, gson

(This post is meant to be a [canonical question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) with a sample answer provided below.)

---

I'm trying to deserialize some JSON content into a custom POJO type with [`Gson#fromJson(String, Class)`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29).

This piece of code

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"nestedPojo\":[{\"name\":null, \"value\":42}]}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.fromJson(json, Pojo.class);
    }
}

class Pojo {
    NestedPojo nestedPojo;
}

class NestedPojo {
    String name;
    int value;
}
```

throws the follow exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 16 path $.nestedPojo
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:200)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:103)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:196)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:724)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:696)
    at com.example.Sample.main(Sample.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 16 path $.nestedPojo
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:387)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:189)
    ... 7 more
```

Why can't Gson properly convert my JSON text to my POJO type?

Comment: Might be worth adding a second answer for the inverse error. Expected array but was object

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As the exception message states

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 16 path $.nestedPojo
```

while deserializing, Gson was expecting a JSON object, but found a JSON array. Since it couldn't convert from one to the other, it threw this exception.

The JSON format is described [here](http://json.org/). In short, it defines the following types: objects, arrays, strings, numbers, `null`, and the boolean values `true` and `false`.

In Gson (and most JSON parsers), the following mappings exist: a JSON string maps to a Java `String`; a JSON number maps to a Java `Number` type; a JSON array maps to a `Collection` type or an array type; a JSON object maps to a Java `Map` type or, typically, a custom [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) type (not mentioned previously); `null` maps to Java's `null`, and the boolean values map to Java's `true` and `false`.

Gson iterates through the JSON content that you provide and tries to deserialize it to the corresponding type you've requested. If the content doesn't match or can't be converted to the expected type, it'll throw a corresponding exception.

In your case, you provided the following JSON

```
{
    "nestedPojo": [
        {
            "name": null,
            "value": 42
        }
    ]
}
```

At the root, this is a JSON object which contains a member named `nestedPojo` which is a JSON array. That JSON array contains a single element, another JSON object with two members. Considering the mappings defined earlier, you'd expect this JSON to map to a Java object which has a field named `nestedPojo` of some `Collection` or array type, where that types defines two fields named `name` and `value`, respectively.

However, you've defined your `Pojo` type as having a field

```
NestedPojo nestedPojo;
```

that is neither an array type, nor a `Collection` type. Gson can't deserialize the corresponding JSON for this field.

Instead, you have 3 options:

- Change your JSON to match the expected type

  ```
  {
      "nestedPojo": {
          "name": null,
          "value": 42
      }
  }
  ```
- Change your `Pojo` type to expect a `Collection` or array type

  ```
  List<NestedPojo> nestedPojo; // consider changing the name and using @SerializedName
  NestedPojo[] nestedPojo;
  ```
- Write and register a custom deserializer for `NestedPojo` with your own parsing rules. For example

  ```
  class Custom implements JsonDeserializer<NestedPojo> {
      @Override
      public NestedPojo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
          NestedPojo nestedPojo = new NestedPojo();
          JsonArray jsonArray = json.getAsJsonArray();
          if (jsonArray.size() != 1) {
              throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected json");
          }
          JsonObject jsonObject = jsonArray.get(0).getAsJsonObject(); // get only element
          JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get("name");
          if (!jsonElement.isJsonNull()) {
              nestedPojo.name = jsonElement.getAsString();
          }
          nestedPojo.value = jsonObject.get("value").getAsInt();
          return nestedPojo;
      }
  }

  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(NestedPojo.class, new Custom()).create();
  ```

Answer (score 7):

```
class Pojo {
  NestedPojo nestedPojo;
}
```

in your json you have an array of nestedPojo
so either you change the code

```
  NestedPojo[] nestedPojo;
```

or you change the json string

```
String json = "{\"nestedPojo\":{\"name\":null, \"value\":42}}";
```