# How can I use an object inside a HashMap when parsing multidimensional JSON with GSON in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

If I have JSON DATA like:

```
{
   "status":200,

   "carList":[
       {
          "carId":121,
          "carName":"Cat",
      },
      {
         "carId":122,
         "carName":"Snek",
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to Use GSON to create the objects by:

```
Cars cars = gson.fromJson(api.response(), Cars.class);
```

Using the two classes like this:

```
Class Cars{
    public String status;
    public Hashmap<String, Car> carList;
}

Class Car{
    public String carId;
    public String carName;
}
```

From what I am reading my problem is putting an object inside of the HashMap.

**At the end of the day I need to be able to loop the "carLis" to display it in a table but I am not sure what my approach should be.**

Comment: A JSON array won't map to a `HashMap`. Change it to a `List<Car>`. Let your clients generate the `HashMap` or expose it separately.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How do you know when to use a list or an array list like siriraghavan says?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33621809/438154).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`carList` is an Array of Objects and not a hashmap.
Try changing the type of carList to `ArrayList`

```
Class Cars{
    public String status;
    public ArrayList<Car> carList;
}
```

You can loop over the ArrayList for the elements

Comment: Thank you! this is what I needed to do!