# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 5921 path $.data[5].courier.data

Tags: java, android, json, response

I have this model object Courier :

```
public class Courier {
    @SerializedName("data")
    private List<User> data = null;

    public Courier() {
    }

    public Courier(List<User> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<User> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<User> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

I get this response from server:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 446,
            "courier": {
                "data": []
            },
            "title": "гром",
            "description": "Логойский тракт 24 в России в начале следующей",
            "departure": "ChIJPQKUckNv2UYRLr1NasgXZ08",
            "arrival": "EkHQodC10YDQtdCx0YDRj9C90YvQuSDQv9C10YDQtdGD0LvQvtC6LCDQnNC-0YHQutCy0LAsINCg0L7RgdGB0LjRjw"
        },
        {
            "id": 438,
            "courier": {
                "data": []
            },
            "title": "тест",
            "description": "гппг лмш ш ш ш ш г У меня на сковородке стоит ли брать сва в кино мы все равно обсуждаем",
            "departure": "ChIJH10nmDnP20YR-n7Kq6Whd5w",
            "arrival": "Ej_QnNC-0YHQutCy0L7RgNC10YbQutCw0Y8g0YPQu9C40YbQsCwg0JzQvtGB0LrQstCwLCDQoNC-0YHRgdC40Y8"
        },
        {
            "id": 439,
            "courier": {
                "data": []
            },
            "title": "лаьаьаат",
            "description": "лала слат алс ал ала ал кща да аьад",
            "departure": "ChIJH7D4cTnP20YRKlzSCnP6Mak",
            "arrival": "Ej_QnNC-0YHQutCy0L7RgNC10YbQutCw0Y8g0YPQu9C40YbQsCwg0JzQvtGB0LrQstCwLCDQoNC-0YHRgdC40Y8"
        },
        {
            "id": 442,
            "courier": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 122,
                    "email": null,
                    "phone": "73339999999",
                    "photo": null,
                    "rating": 0
                }
            },
            "title": "картошечка",
            "description": "Крупная сортированная",
            "departure": "ChIJnZRv1jnP20YRWiezW55d1tA",
            "arrival": "ChIJpfH6UJtp1EYRlhM20g-jzF4"
        }
    ]
}
```

If object `courier` not have data, i get array `"data": []`, if object `courier` has data, i get object :

```
"courier": {
                "data": {
                    "id": 122,
                    "email": null,
                    "phone": "73339999999",
                    "photo": null,
                    "rating": 0
                }
            }
```

And then I get error... Please give me advice how handle this case in android application...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is one of the most common mistakes when you start to use JSON with a client, for android please refer to this [tutorial](http://sachinpatil.com/blog/2012/07/03/gson/) to understand

the best source to understand this kind of mistake is to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621808/why-does-gson-fromjson-throw-a-jsonsyntaxexception-expected-some-type-but-was-s)
a canonical SO post.

Is better to read it  and understand it, that asking for a simple solution because you will go really often into this error.

> while deserializing, Gson was expecting a JSON object, but found a
>   JSON array

A JSON Object is wrapped by a `{`

A JSON Array  is wrapped by a `[`

What you need is to adapt your class Courier, to deserialize in the right way the JSON response.

take in mind that; a `JSON array` become deserialized in java as a Collection type or an array type;
PLEASE notice that is confusing to use two times data

on top of everything, the first data is

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private Data[] data;

    public Data[] getData ()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData (Data[] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [data = "+data+"]";
    }
}
```

**Data.class**

```
public class Data
{
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private Courier courier;

    private String arrival;

    private String departure;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle ()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle (String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription ()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription (String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Courier getCourier ()
    {
        return courier;
    }

    public void setCourier (Courier courier)
    {
        this.courier = courier;
    }

    public String getArrival ()
    {
        return arrival;
    }

    public void setArrival (String arrival)
    {
        this.arrival = arrival;
    }

    public String getDeparture ()
    {
        return departure;
    }

    public void setDeparture (String departure)
    {
        this.departure = departure;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [id = "+id+", title = "+title+", description = "+description+", courier = "+courier+", arrival = "+arrival+", departure = "+departure+"]";
    }
}
```

**Courier.class**

```
public class Courier
{
    private String[] data;

    public String[] getData ()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData (String[] data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [data = "+data+"]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you just to create a class `Data` with fields `id`, `email`, etc. And make field `Data data`  in the class `Courier` instead of a `List<> data`

EDIT: then you can use a `JsonDeserializer`. Just remove `@SerializedName("data")` over the `Data` field, so that the Json will not parse this field. Then create a class:

```
public class CourierDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Courier> {
    @Override
    public Courier deserialize(final JsonElement json, final Type type,
                                  final JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        Courier result = new Gson().fromJson(json, Courier.class);

        try {
            if (json != null) {
                result.setData((Data) context.deserialize(json, Data.class));
            }
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            result.setData(null);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

and finally register it where you create your `GsonBuilder`:

```
GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(Courier.class, new CourierDeserializer());
mGson = gson.create();
builder.setConverter(new GsonConverter(mGson));
```

if you use Retrofit.

Comment: sory, but no, it will error - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY