# Parse array of objects JSON response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to parse a JSON without any key except the object.

For example:

```
[
  {
    "OBJECT1":{
                 ....
              }
  },
     "OBJECT2":{
                 ....
                }
  }
]
```

In this case i am trying to parse this JSON like a List objects, and the class Objects include the values inside these objects. I don't know if i am doing right.

The error response of Gson is

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I am parsing the JSON correctly??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Gson fromJson throw a JsonSyntaxException: Expected some type but was some other type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621808/why-does-gson-fromjson-throw-a-jsonsyntaxexception-expected-some-type-but-was-s) and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Comment: Post your code, the way you are parsing it

Comment: You are trying to parse JSONObject but it is actually a JSONArray, So try to parse JSONArray first.

Comment: you are parsing it incorrectly. You need to fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can using Gson [library](https://github.com/google/gson). if we assume your object is a person class like this

```
class Person{
String name;
int age;
}
```

and your json response like this

```
[
   {
      "OBJECT1":{
         "name":"mohamed",
         "age":21
      },
      "OBJECT2":{
         "name":"shalan",
         "age":21
      }
   }
]
```

you need to create a class to reflect each object in your json 
for Object1

```
public class OBJECT1 {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private Integer age;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Integer getAge() {
return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
this.age = age;
}

}
```

and for your Object2

```
public class OBJECT2 {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("age")
@Expose
private Integer age;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Integer getAge() {
return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
this.age = age;
}

}
```

and this is a person class for holding your objects

```
public class Person {

@SerializedName("OBJECT1")
@Expose
private OBJECT1 oBJECT1;
@SerializedName("OBJECT2")
@Expose
private OBJECT2 oBJECT2;

public OBJECT1 getOBJECT1() {
return oBJECT1;
}

public void setOBJECT1(OBJECT1 oBJECT1) {
this.oBJECT1 = oBJECT1;
}

public OBJECT2 getOBJECT2() {
return oBJECT2;
}

public void setOBJECT2(OBJECT2 oBJECT2) {
this.oBJECT2 = oBJECT2;
}

}
```

to convert your json array to a list of your object List

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonOutput = "your json result is here";
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){}.getType();
List<Persopn> persons = (List<Person>) gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);
```

Comment: After array one more json object is there.

Comment: can you comment with your json result

Comment: [{
 "OBJECT1":{
    "name": "mohamed",
    "age": 21
  },
 "OBJECT2":{
    "name": "shalan",
    "age": 21
  } }
]

Comment: and then then also you have to create `OBJECT3` class and `OBJECT4` class and .... `OBJECTN` class

Comment: actually true, based on your json.

Comment: Not mine json ... also because seems like name `OBJECTX` is dynamic, your solution (which is just a copy from some generator) is not a solution ... not mention that the question is *I am parsing the JSON correctly??* ... and there is no code **so basically this question cannot be answered**

Comment: you can use this website [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for creating your POJOs from a json response

Comment: *You can using Gson library.* hehehehe he is using already *The error response of Gson is `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException`*

Comment: if you don't know the key of objects returned, you just need to put this objects inside array instead of object.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like syntax error, try this:-

```
[
  {
    "OBJECT1":[            {le:"Dashobard",level:"01"},{name:"About Us",level:"02"},{name:"Contact Us",level:"03"},{name:"Dashobard",level:"04"}
              ]
  },
   {  "OBJECT2":[            {le:"Dashobard",level:"01"},{name:"About Us",level:"02"},{name:"Contact Us",level:"03"},{name:"Dashobard",level:"04"}
              ]
  }
]
```