# Converting JSON string to object returns "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING"

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a JSON response coming back from my server in the format:

```
[
    {
        "id": "one",
        "values": {
            "name": "John",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "two",
        "values": {
            "name": "Bob",
        }
    }
]
```

Here is the class I've set up:

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("values")
    private List<String> values;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Here is my code to parse the JSON into a list of objects:

```
String response = serverResponseHere;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(response);

Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<TestClass>>(){}.getType();
List<TestClass> values = gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

However, I get the following error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

What's going on here?

Comment: according your values its just object array not list string

Comment: using the object as a list has caused the error . this is the right: = Type collectionType = new TypeToken<TestClass>(){}.getType(); . also your son is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You're taking your JSON response content

```
String response = serverResponseHere;
```

and converting it to JSON

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(response);
```

This produces a JSON string containing your content. That looks like

```
"[\n    {\n        \"id\": \"one\",\n        \"values\": {\n            \"name\": \"John\",\n        }\n    },\n    {\n        \"id\": \"two\",\n        \"values\": {\n            \"name\": \"Bob\",\n        }\n    }\n]\n"
```

When you try to deserialize that as a `List<TestClass>`, it obviously fails because it's a JSON String instead of a JSON Array.

Don't serialize your content to JSON before deserializing it, it's already JSON.

---

Others have mentioned this, your `values` field doesn't match what your JSON content. See here for how to fix that:

- [Why does Gson fromJson throw a JsonSyntaxException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621808/why-does-gson-fromjson-throw-a-jsonsyntaxexception-expected-begin-object-but-wa)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Change your server response json from :

```
[
    {
        "id": "one",
        "values": {
            "name": "John",
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "two",
        "values": {
            "name": "Bob",
        }
    }
]
```

To :

```
[
    {
        "id": "one",
        "values": [
            {"name": "John"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "two",
        "values": [
            {"name": "Bob"}
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Still won't work, as `{"name": "John"}` is not a string

Comment: That should not be also cause it need to be a json object inside json array. Error is it's getting string where array is expected.

Comment: `List<String>` expects something like `["John", "Bob"]`